# Google Chrome not loading any webpages, meanwhile FireFox and other internet based services works just fine. Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: google-chrome, internet

I've encountered strange problem. Yesterday my Google Chrome browser was working just fine but today it won't load any webpages and it seems like it is cut off from internet completely because I cannot even send automatic report to Google. I'm not super user of Linux so it's a problem for me to solve it alone. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu: 20.04.1 LTS and Google Chrome:Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I'm not using any kind of firewalls, antyviruses etc.

Regards, Daniel.

Comment: Try to uninstall Chrome (save bookmarks), scrub all its folders and reinstall.

Comment: Hi. I've tried that already. Didn't work.

Comment: Does Incognito mode work?

Comment: Try asking this question on AskUbuntu, I think there will be more people able to answer it there. Maybe the moderator can move the question there?

Comment: It seems like the problem has gone away?

Comment: @harrymc Lol how did You know. It's working in incognito mode. Normal mode still doesn't work. Any ideas what can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't speak to Chrome on Ubuntu but had the same issue on android two days ago.  verified chrome was updated under help about, and cleared all my cache and temp files, still didn't work, used Brave instead and yesterday chrome just started working again and working today without error really kind of odd.

Comment: LOL I've checked Chrome right now and it's working flawless. I have no idead what's going on but it's working. Thanks for Your engagement.

Answer (score 0):

Something needs to be wrong as I commented on NickA's answer yesterday Chrome was working fine. Today I've got the same issue. FireFox works fine, Chrome don't have access to the internet. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this does not happen when using Chrome in Incognito Mode is a big hint.

In Incognito Mode extensions are disabled. Since Chrome does not control how
these extensions handle your personal data when you search the Internet,
the solution is to disable them all by default.

This working in Incognito Mode means that some Chrome extension is responsible
for your problem.

I suggest to  enter `chrome://extensions/` in the address bar and examine your
extensions. You may disable them one by one until you reach the problematic one,
which you can then remove.

Comment: Hmmm second thing is that I was unable to clear all cache (ctrl+shift+del, all boxes ticked, clear all, it was processing for 20 mins and didn't finish). To be honest I've had installed just one extension. It was an uBlock Origin. Strange. I've tried doing clean reinstallation and it's working fine (I've reinstalled uBlock). We will see what's gonna happen.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/usy3yr/chrome_and_chromium_not_loading_any_pages_2204/

This was (in my case) a problem after installing Citrix Workspace. The solution is to run:
sudo mv /etc/ld.so.preload /etc/ld.so.preload.org

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The only way to get chrome working was to start google via terminal with the following command `google-chrome -v=1`.
Also I still don't understand why this is fixing the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).